# Which version of Ubuntu is recommended for Samsung N270 notebook?

Tags: samsung, distro-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find out which version and derivate of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivate-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardware)

I have just installed 12.04 LTS 32-bit because it was recommended to me, but it seems slow, slightly slower than the EX family edition Windows which came with the notebook and which I used for 3 years.

This makes me wonder if this is the correct version of Ubuntu for me, 
or if I maybe need to install a driver for my built in graphic card? Or something else.

It's a Samsung N270 notebook.

- Intel Atom cpu N270 @ 1.6GH X 2.
- 1GB RAM
- I am not sure the type of graphics card I just know that it is built-in and from Intel.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the requirements listed in the Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop#System_requirements), your build should be more than capable of handling 12.04. I run it myself on a 9 year-old machine with only a single core (and considerably less memory) fine.

Definitely install your graphics driver. Type `lspci | grep 'VGA'` in at the command line ('terminal' application) to find out your graphics card. Search for the model number to find out which package, if any, you need to install to get the relevant driver.